# CIVI Dashboard display settings broken in Wordpress install

Tags: wordpress

New to CIVI. Working with an install of CIVI in Wordpress. When logged as Admin AND visit the Civi Dashboard, it loads, but displays broken, with settings and displays all over the place. Attached is a screenshot of the 'Manage Events Tab' as an example of what the settings currently look like.

I have checked civicrm.settings.php for BASE URL issues etc, and all is pointing to the correct WP install in the directory.

Has anyone experienced this issue and can shine some much need light on.

Many thanks[image: DISPLAYSETTINGS]

Comment: are you using default wordpress theme - please try to reinstall civicrm (latest version) if you are using default theme

Comment: Is the path to the CSS file correct? Also probably worth disabling all other WordPress plugins, just to see if anything's interfering.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I will check the path to the CSS File, Ive disabled  the plugins - no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I would double check the `define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'http://example.com/' );` line and make sure that the url exactly matches the `Site Address (URL)` in http://yoursite.com//wp-admin/options-general.php

I've had issues where one is http://www.example.com  and the other is http://example.com

Next check the CiviCRM resource URL:  http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/url&reset=1 The `CiviCRM Resource URL` parameter should point to http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/

Lastly, I'd fire up Firebug or chrome inspector and see if there are any console errors.  I'd want to know which css file is loading for civicrm.  For me it is `/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css`